# "message" event is not fired when using postMessage

Tags: javascript, node.js, iframe

I want to communicate between the main window and an iframe that is loaded in page. I did this thing in the past (the code still works), but however I cannot use it in another project. I create an example to reproduce the issue. It has a basic server side (that just serves some files) using [***`Le Statique`*** module](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/node-statique).

The most important part is the client side, but let's start with the server:

### Server (NodeJS)

Creates two servers (one listening on `8000` and another one listening on `9000`).

```
// Dependencies
var Statique = require("statique")
  , Http = require('http')
  ;

Http.createServer(new Statique({
    root: __dirname + "/receiver"
}).setRoutes({
    "/": "/html/index.html"
}).serve).listen(8000);

Http.createServer(new Statique({
    root: __dirname + "/sender"
}).setRoutes({
    "/": "/html/index.html"
}).serve).listen(9000);
```

### Client

#### Receiver

```
...
window.onload = function () {
    addEventListener("message", function (e) {
        // This part is never fired!
        console.log("2", e.data);
    }, false);
};
...
```

#### Sender

```
...
<body>
    <iframe src="http://localhost:8000" frameborder="0" id="iframe"></iframe>
    <script>
        iframe.contentWindow.postMessage("hi", "*");
    </script>
</body>
...
```

However, `"message"` events from iframe are not fired. Why?

I don't see any error in console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `iframe` window is not completely loaded (nobody listens for `"message"` events).

By listening for iframe load event we are sure that everything was loaded and we can emit the event:

```
iframe.onload = function () {
    iframe.contentWindow.postMessage("hi", "*");
};
```